# Как встроить график в форму в Qt Designer?

Tags: python, pyqt5, matplotlib, qt-designer, pyqtgraph

[image: Форма]

Объясните, пожалуйста, как встроить график *matplotlib* или *PyQtGraph* в окно приложения, которое подготовлено в  *Qt Designer*.

Допустим у меня есть обычные данные:

```
X = [1, 2, 3] , 
Y = [4, 5, 6]
```

Я использую библиотеку *matplotlib*, как вывести функцию на `plt.plot(X,Y)` на форму. Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: https://pythonspot.com/pyqt5-matplotlib/ может это поможет

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Встраивание пользовательских виджетов в `Qt Designer`

`Qt Designer` поддерживает механизм использования виджетов-заполнителей для представления 
ваших пользовательских или внешних виджетов в вашем дизайне.

Принцип использования заполнителей в `Qt Designer`:

1. Создайте пользовательский интерфейс как обычно в `Qt Designer`.
2. Добавьте виджет-заполнитель для представления пользовательского виджета, который вы добавляете.
3. Скажите Qt заменить ваш местозаполнитель фактическим виджетом при создании пользовательского интерфейса.
   В Qt этот последний шаг называется продвижением (как продвижением базового класса).
   Вы можете использовать QWidget, общий базовый класс всех виджетов Qt.

`PyQtGraph` - это популярная альтернатива, использующая встроенный `Qt QGraphicsScene` для обеспечения 
быстрого масштабирования, масштабирования и поведения перетаскивания, 
которое кажется естественной частью вашего приложения.

Независимо от того, используете ли вы `PyQtGraph` или `maplotlib` для своих потребностей в графике, 
виджеты `plot canvas` графика **не доступны** в `Qt Designer`.

Если у вас еще не установлен `PyQtGraph`, вы можете установить его, используя:

```
pip install pyqtgraph
```

---

1. Сначала откройте `Qt Designer` и создайте новое `QMainWindow` как обычно.
2. Далее нам нужно добавить виджет-заполнитель. 
   Поскольку нет подходящего базового класса для виджета графика `PyQtGraph`, 
   мы будем использовать базовый `QWidget` в качестве заполнителя. 
   Выберите виджет на левой боковой панели и поместите его в центр окна.
   Дайте виджету имя, например,  `GraphWidget`. Это просто тег для ссылки на элемент в коде.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Щелкните правой кнопкой мыши виджет и выберите `Promote to...`  в контекстном меню виджета. 
Продвижение `QWidget` указывает на то, что его следует заменить указанным подклассом, 
в нашем случае - графическим виджетом `PyQtGraph`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вам будет представлен диалог для указания пользовательского класса виджета, которым станет виджет-заполнитель.

`header file` - это имя модуля Python, используемого для импорта класса, а именно `pyqtgraph`.

Укажите `PlotWidget` в качестве имени класса виджета, чтобы заменить его.
Имя, которое вы используете для файла, не имеет значения, но обычно хорошей идеей будет называть его как класса, который вы собираетесь создать с ним.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь виджет превращается в холст для построения графика. 
Но вы не сможете увидеть какие-либо изменения в `Qt Designer`. 
Сохраните окно, например как `mainwindow.ui` в том же каталоге, что и ваше приложение `PyQt.`

---

**Загрузка файла .ui**

Теперь у нас есть файл `mainwindow.ui`, содержащий наше пользовательский интерфейс. 
Загрузим его в наше приложение.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
import pyqtgraph as pg

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Загрузите страницу интерфейса
        uic.loadUi('mainwindow.ui', self)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Вы должны увидеть окно с вашим виджетом, преобразованным в графический виджет `PyQtGraph`.

---

Теперь создадим функцию для создания простого графика данных `x` и `y`.

```
import sys  
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot
import pyqtgraph as pg


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Загрузите страницу интерфейса
        uic.loadUi('mainPlotWidget.ui', self)

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        grid.addWidget(self.graphWidget, 0, 0)

        self.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], [30,32,34,32,33,31,29,32,35,45])

    # мы добавили метод plot(), который принимает два массива: 
    # temperature и hour, затем строит данные с помощью метода graphWidget.plot().

    def plot(self, hour, temperature):
        self.graphWidget.plot(hour, temperature)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: 444_]

Comment: Огромное спасибо за столь подробный ответ!

Comment: что делать, если не отображается виджет, преобразованный в графический виджет PyQtGraph?
выдает много ошибок? и это в самом конце ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotwidget'

Comment: @оля что делать ? Задать новый вопрос, приложить пример, который демонстрирует проблему и описать что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.