# Как добавить свой атрибут в класс QPushButton

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qpushbutton

У меня в форме модуль **convtest.py** созданной в *Qt Designer* **`400`** кнопок. 
Я хочу к каждой кнопке добавить атрибут `pos_value`, но перспектива писать 400 строк, чтобы каждой кнопке добавить этот атрибут, не из приятных.

Я понимаю, что нужно как-то подлезть в конструктор класса `QPushButton` и там прописать этот атрибут, чтобы при создании объекта `QPushButton` сразу был этот атрибут.

Надеюсь я понятно изъяснился. Простите мой уровень знаний *Python* и *ООП* достаточно слабый. Надеюсь получить пример в виде кода. Конкретно мне надо, чтобы при создании экземпляра, сразу появлялся данный атрибут у кнопки.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
from convtest import Ui_MainWindow


# Главное окно
class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()  
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


        self.ui.pushButton.pos_value = [0, 0, 0, 0]  # Атрибут кнопки
        self.ui.pushButton1.pos_value = [0, 0, 0, 0]  # Атрибут кнопки
```

Comment: какой-то из ответов решает вашу проблему?

Answer (score 2):

я уже отвечал на вопрос о `Встраивание пользовательских виджетов в Qt Designer`
[Как загрузить график на форму в PyQT?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1091615/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2-pyqt/1091676#1091676)

...
Добавьте кнопку.
Щелкните правой кнопкой мыши виджет и выберите `Promote to...`
в контекстном меню виджета.
Продвижение `QPushButton` указывает на то, что его следует заменить указанным подклассом,
в нашем случае - графическим виджетом `MyPushButton`.

`header file` - это имя модуля Python, используемого для импорта класса,
а именно `my_push_button`.      (my_push_button.py)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**my_pb.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>392</width>
    <height>286</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <widget class="MyPushButton" name="pushButton">
        <property name="text">
         <string>1</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="1">
       <widget class="MyPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
        <property name="text">
         <string>2</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="2">
       <widget class="MyPushButton" name="pushButton_3">
        <property name="text">
         <string>3</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="0">
       <widget class="MyPushButton" name="pushButton_4">
        <property name="text">
         <string>4</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="1">
       <widget class="MyPushButton" name="pushButton_5">
        <property name="text">
         <string>5</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="2">
       <widget class="MyPushButton" name="pushButton_6">
        <property name="text">
         <string>6</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="2" column="0">
       <widget class="MyPushButton" name="pushButton_7">
        <property name="text">
         <string>7</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="2" column="1">
       <widget class="MyPushButton" name="pushButton_8">
        <property name="text">
         <string>8</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="2" column="2">
       <widget class="MyPushButton" name="pushButton_9">
        <property name="text">
         <string>9</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>392</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>MyPushButton</class>
   <extends>QPushButton</extends>
   <header>my_push_button</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**Выполните**

```
pyuic5 my_pb.ui -o my_pb.py -x
```

**Создайте**

**my_push_button.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class MyPushButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyPushButton, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.pos_value = [0, 0, 0, 0]               # Атрибут кнопки
        
        self.clicked.connect(lambda: print(self.text(), self.pos_value))
```

**Запустите**

```
python my_pb.py
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```py
for i in range(400):
    getattr(self.ui, f"pushButton{i}").pos_value = [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Но вообще, всем Вашим 400 кнопкам следовало бы быть в одном списке, потому что это костыли.

---

Если необходимо, чтобы этот атрибут был у каждой кнопки, то можно сделать вот так (всё это проделать перед созданием формы):

```py
class MyButton(QPushButton):  # Объявляем новый класс
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # Вызываем конструктор родителя
        self.pos_value = [0, 0, 0, 0]  # Добавляем атрибут


QPushButton = MyButton  # Заменяем стандартную ссылку на новый класс
```

Но это **очень** грязно. Если Вы собираетесь далее этот код куда-то распространять, то так делать не следует. Так же, если Вы сами в будущем вернётесь к этому коду, то Вы будете не рады такому "сюрпризу", оставленному самому себе.

Comment: Вариант не подходит . Во первых имена кнопок разные . Во вторых что если мне нужно будет еще добавить кнопку . Мне нужно что бы сразу при создании экземпляра создавался данный атрибут без надобности создавать длинный список и через цикл добавлять . Мой косяк не указал точно .

Comment: @eswcpoker Тогда Вам надо создавать наследуемый класс от `QPushButton` и везде использовать его вместо обычного QPushButton. Но я не знаю, умеет ли Qt Designer работать с кастомными классами. В конструктор уже имеющейся кнопки Вы не добавите своё поле без извращений, т.к. эти классы написаны на C++ и скомпилированы.

Comment: Да я понял про какое извращение речь идет )) . Спасибо теперь я понял почему у меня не создался там этот атрибут

Comment: @eswcpoker Обновил ответ.

Comment: да, действительно `QPushButton = MyButton` - это плохой способ.