# Как вставить график в QFrame?

Tags: python, pyqt5, matplotlib, qt-designer, qlayout

Как сделать так, чтобы построенный график отображался в `QFrame` ("`insert_frame`")?

Сейчас создается новое окно игнорируя форму созданую в *Qt Designer*.

Как сделать так, чтобы график вставлялся именно в уже существующий элемент ("`insert_frame`")?

**ui_example.py**:

```
#from ui_example import Ui_DialogWindowAccept
import sys
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import random

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_DialogWindowAccept(object):
    def setupUi(self, DialogWindowAccept):
        DialogWindowAccept.setObjectName("DialogWindowAccept")
        DialogWindowAccept.resize(620, 520)
        DialogWindowAccept.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        DialogWindowAccept.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16000, 16000))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(DialogWindowAccept)
        self.centralwidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16000, 16000))
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.header = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.header.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 70))
        self.header.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 70))
        self.header.setStyleSheet("")
        self.header.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.header.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.header.setObjectName("header")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.header)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.header)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.header)
        self.insert_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.insert_frame.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(600, 310))
        self.insert_frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.insert_frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.insert_frame.setObjectName("insert_frame")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.insert_frame)
        DialogWindowAccept.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(DialogWindowAccept)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(DialogWindowAccept)

    def retranslateUi(self, DialogWindowAccept):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        DialogWindowAccept.setWindowTitle(_translate("DialogWindowAccept", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("DialogWindowAccept", "Example"))
```

**main.py**:

```py
class MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)


class GraphWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_DialogWindowAccept()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)

        self.canvas = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)

        n_data = 50
        self.xdata = list(range(n_data))
        self.ydata = [random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(n_data)]

        GraphWindow.update_plot(self)

        self.show()

    def update_plot(self):

        self.ydata = self.ydata[1:] + [random.randint(0, 10)]
        self.canvas.axes.cla()
        self.canvas.axes.plot(self.xdata, self.ydata, 'r')
        self.canvas.draw()
```

Привел минимальный воспроизводимый пример.

Структура в Qt Designer:

```
DialogWindowAccept->centralwidget->header(->label), insert_frame
```

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТ версия 3-8 Спасибо. Тобишь, ,matplotlib.pyplot не выйдет использовать, лишь pyqtgraph, как там в примере?

Comment: Лучше - да, конечно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет вы не создается новое окно, игнорируя форму созданую в Qt Designer,
вы устанавливает виджет `canvas` как центральный виджет главного окна.

```
self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)
```

И таким образом вы все затерли что создавали в Qt Designer.

---

Да, вы можете в Qt Designer встроить практический любой виджет.
@ПИТОНИСТверсия3-8  ссылается на мой ответ, где я рассказал как это делать.

---

В вашем случае, также возможно, просто создать менеджер компоновки

```
hlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.insert_frame)
```

и добавить виджет

```
hlayout.addWidget(self.canvas)
```

---

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class Ui_DialogWindowAccept(object):
    def setupUi(self, DialogWindowAccept):
        DialogWindowAccept.setObjectName("DialogWindowAccept")
        DialogWindowAccept.resize(620, 520)
        DialogWindowAccept.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        DialogWindowAccept.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16000, 16000))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(DialogWindowAccept)
        self.centralwidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16000, 16000))
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.header = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.header.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 70))
        self.header.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 70))
        self.header.setStyleSheet("")
        self.header.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.header.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.header.setObjectName("header")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.header)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.header)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.header)
        self.insert_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.insert_frame.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(600, 310))
        self.insert_frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.insert_frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.insert_frame.setObjectName("insert_frame")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.insert_frame)
        DialogWindowAccept.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(DialogWindowAccept)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(DialogWindowAccept)

    def retranslateUi(self, DialogWindowAccept):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        DialogWindowAccept.setWindowTitle(_translate("DialogWindowAccept", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("DialogWindowAccept", "Example"))
        

class MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)


class GraphWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_DialogWindowAccept):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
# ???        self.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)

        self.canvas = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        
        hlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.insert_frame)              # +++ 
        hlayout.addWidget(self.canvas)                                  # +++ 
        
        n_data = 50
        self.xdata = list(range(n_data))
        self.ydata = [random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(n_data)]

        self.update_plot()

    def update_plot(self):
        self.ydata = self.ydata[1:] + [random.randint(0, 10)]
        self.canvas.axes.cla()
        self.canvas.axes.plot(self.xdata, self.ydata, 'r')
        self.canvas.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = GraphWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо)

Comment: @Artem Bragslav пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

[Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1091615/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2-qt-designer) - вопрос на **StackOverflow**, очень похожий на Ваш. Делайте лучше с **PyQTGraph**, а не с **matplotlib.pyplot**

Comment: Если Вам помог ответ, нажмите галочку